# How to validate angular apps token in Web API and what configurations required in Azure Portal

Tags: angular, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

I've been struggling to solve one issue from one week.
I've an angular application that is authenticated with Microsoft Graph this flow is working fine.
We have a backed that is open to public initially but now I wanted to protect that API using Azure AD authentication, I'm done with this till here.

In Azure Portal I've added two App registration for UI and API, Somehow, I need to establish the connectivity among these app registrations that I'm looking for?

Currently I'm getting following issue
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjbUK.png)

Any reference links would also suffice.

Comment: Please do not post error messages as images. [Check here why.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I created two Azure AD Applications, and **To establish the connection between two Applications I exposed an API** for the backend application:

[image]

In the Frontend Application add the API permission like below:

[image]

While generating the token, make sure to use scope as **`api://ClientIDofBackendApp/.default`** like below:

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:api://ClientIDofBackendApp/app.access
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:RedirectUri
code:code
```

[image]

To resolve the error, make sure the **aud** is **`api://ClientID/.default`** after connecting the Applications like below:

[image]

In your code make sure to change scope in the config file like below:

```java
var scope ="api://ClientID/.default";
```

**Reference:**

[Using multiple APIs in Angular and ASP.NET Core with Azure AD authentication by damienbod](https://damienbod.com/2020/12/08/using-multiple-apis-in-angular-and-asp-net-core-with-azure-ad-authentication/)